# layoutIfNeeded not working in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c

`layoutIfNeeded` is not working properly in iPad but it is working on iPhone. I want to a circular button. On the iPhone the circle is generated properly but in iPad it looks like a rhombus shape.

```
_btnthur.layer.cornerRadius = _btnthur.frame.size.width/2;  
[self._btnthur layoutIfNeeded];
```

**Expected Result :**

[image: expected]

**Current Output:**

[image: current]

Comment: Could you add a screen shot of what should happen, and what is happening? Also in your code here you are setting the cornerRadius on `btnthur`, but telling `btnSat` to layout.

Comment: Also, you should not be calling `layoutIfNeeded`, you should be calling `setNeedsLayout` and allow the run cycle to coalesce layout calls for performance.

Comment: @GeorgeGreen: you might want to provide an answer (as an answer) so OP will be able to close this question. :)

Comment: @RokJarc Thanks, I was initially just looking for clarification, but got a bit carried away 

Answer (score 1):

I can see two main issues here:

1. In your code here you are setting the cornerRadius on `btnthur`, but telling `btnSat` to layout.
2. You should not be calling `layoutIfNeeded`, you should be calling `setNeedsLayout` and allow the run cycle to coalesce layout calls for performance.

Hope this helps :)

---

Edit for updated question:

Your corner radius is wrong in the second one, it is much too large. Can you check that the frame is correctly set on the button at the point you are setting the corner radius?

You may want to move your code

```
_btnthur.layer.cornerRadius = _btnthur.frame.size.width/2;  
[self._btnthur setNeedsLayout];
```

into `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (depending on view or view controller) and make sure that the corner radius is always updated when the frame (or more importantly, the size) is set.

Comment: sorry 1st one is mistake from my side. that is not my issue

Comment: Ok, could we get some screen shots of desired vs. experienced behaviour?

Comment: i added in the question itself please verify that

Comment: Updated answer ⬆